How to add reference lines to a violin plot?
I built a plot that contains 3 different violin plots. I want to add 3 different horizontal lines so that in the first plot is at y = 0.44, in the second plot at y = 0.413 and in the third plot at y = 0.375. Something like the red dots on this image.

I tried using "geom_hline" but did not work because I could not find a way to select the values of x since my x axis is not composed of continuous variables.
This is the current code (adapted to the iris dataset) I use to build the plots:
library(tidyverse)
library(modeldata)
?geom_boxplot

data <- iris

ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(Species,level = c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica")),
                 y = Sepal.Length,
                 fill = Species)) +
  geom_violin(fill = "lightgray") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .02, fill= "black") +
  xlab("Species")


This line data <- read.csv("Qualtrics.csv", TRUE, ";") means your question is not reproducible, since we don't have access to your working directory.  Please replace it with the output from dput(data) (or dput(head(data))) if the dataset is large.  Just include enough data to make your question reproducible.

... or you could use an inbuilt dataset e.g. ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_violin()  . This makes it easier for you to get help

You can use geom_segment(...) to tell ggplot where to draw lines
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.75, xend = 1.25, y = 5, yend = 5),
               color = "red",
               linetype = 'longdash',
               linewidth = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.75, xend = 2.25, y = 6, yend = 6),
               color = "red",
               linetype = 'longdash',
               linewidth = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2.75, xend = 3.25, y = 7, yend = 7),
               color = "red",
               linetype = 'longdash',
               linewidth = 1)



Created on 2024-06-10 with reprex v2.1.0

Using geom_segment with custom data:
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x - 0.5, xend = x + 0.5, y = y, yend = y), 
               data = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(5, 6, 7)), 
               colour = "red", linetype = "dashed")


